# Finding and replacing text inside awk block

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I want to find and replace a value inside awk block.

Here is a sample input file to my script

```
P1
10,9:11/18013013582
,10:1
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
11,9:15/310410532169026
,10:60
,167:0
,487:4/IMSI
12,18:15/013329002130500
,19:0
15,9:10/9609610015
,10:1
,14:68
,167:0
,436:5/ABCDE
,487:5/E.164
16,87:1
17,9:10/8013765024
,10:1
,11:1
,12:0
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
23,9:11/13123149810
,10:1
,11:1
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
P3
42,3:1.
,4:3
,300:1.
43,3:1.
,4:3
,300:1.
44,3:0.
,4:7
,300:0.
45,5:0.3
```

And here is the piece of code that I am currently using,

```
nawk -v fname="${filename}" -F '/|:' '

    function isnum(x){return(x==x+0)}

    /P1/,/P3/{
            # Found start increment i reset variables go to next line
            if(/P1/){
                   ++i 
                   fid ="" 
                   count++
                   next
                }

            # Found end validate variable and print go to next line
            if(/P3/){
                printf "%s|",count
                printf "%s|",isnum(fid)?fid:"NULL"
                  next 
                }
            if(!fid && /36,59:*/)
                {
                    fid = $NF
                }
        ' ${filename} >>output.txt
```

Basically, I my input file will contain several P1/P3 blocks, I am taking one block at a time and finding out value from it. Now, what I want to basically do is change the value of first ,11:**1** (i.e the one after 17,9 part) into 11:**2** based on the value of 17,9:10/**8013765024**.

Please note there can be several ,11 before and after but those have to remain unchanged.

Please suggest how to proceed further. I am very new to both awk and sed.

Also, I tried writing a regular expression but could not figure out it properly. Here it is,

```
17[,0-9:\]*[\n]*,11
```

Comment: you want to change the value which was present just after to `17,9:10/8013765024`

Comment: You want to prune this down to a really minimal example and explain how 2 is "based on" 8013765024.  Is that a magic number we should be looking for, or a threshold value, or what are the conditions under which the first ,11:1 should be replaced?

Comment: You cannot apply a regular expression across lines.  You will need something like `/^17[,0-9\:]*$/ { found=1 } found&/^,11/ { do things; found=0 }`

Comment: Your explanation is gibberish. Try rewording it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.

17,9:10/8013765024
,10:1
,11:1

see,
if value after 17,9:10/ i.e. 8013765024 starts with 80 then I want to change this to +118013765024 and also the next ,11:1 value to ,11:2.

I hope I am clear this time. Please let me know if I am not.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this awk command. Whenevre the awk find a number starting with `80` on column2, it gets the next line and then the next line and change it's value to `,11:2` print the other lines as it is.

```
$ awk -F/ '$2~/^80/{print; getline; print; getline; $1=",11.2"}1' file1.txt
P1
10,9:11/18013013582
,10:1
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
11,9:15/310410532169026
,10:60
,167:0
,487:4/IMSI
12,18:15/013329002130500
,19:0
15,9:10/9609610015
,10:1
,14:68
,167:0
,436:5/ABCDE
,487:5/E.164
16,87:1
17,9:10/8013765024
,10:1
,11.2
,12:0
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
23,9:11/13123149810
,10:1
,11:1
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
P3
42,3:1.
,4:3
,300:1.
43,3:1.
,4:3
,300:1.
44,3:0.
,4:7
,300:0.
45,5:0.3
```

Comment: Avinash I dont want to hard code the value 8013765024. I should be able to read the first two letters of 8013765024 and based on it I should be able to decide whether to change from ,11:1 to ,11:2.

If first 2 digits are 80 then only i should change ,11:1 to ,11:2.

To add to this I want 8013765024 also to be appended with +11 (+118013765024)

Comment: You should avoid using `getline` read more here: http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Comment: @Jotne Please stop offering arbitrary "advice" about what not to do. It's (possibly) reasonable to use getline here. Of course, it's still very unclear what the OP actually wants, but getline is not the problem.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't see what the purpose of your `f` variable is. You set it, but never actually use it.

Comment: yes i set it to change the value of the second line after `17,9:10/8013765024`

Comment: @ooga oh sorry this also work `awk -F/ '$2~/^80/{print; getline; print; getline; $1=",11.2"}1' file1.txt`

Comment: I do agree with ooag, `f` is not used anywhere, you set it `f=1` and you clear it `f=0`, but its not used.  After `ED` posted me warning about using  `getline` I have nearly stopped using it, and my code is better and more robust.

Comment: Code edited :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your code will replace values that it is not supposed to..
for eg,

23,9:11/80123149810
,10:1
,11:1
,167:0
,487:5/E.164
It will replace ,11:1 here also which is wrong

Comment: you said after the slash it must be starts with the number 80.

Comment: @AvinashRaj 

It should start with 80 but only one block that is 17,9 block.
I hope I am clear.

Comment: just place two conditions in awk `awk -F/ '$1~/^17,9:10/ && $2~/^80/{print; getline; print; getline; $1=",11.2"}1' file1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F '/|:' '
    $3 == "8013765024" {flag = 1}
    $0 == ",11:1" && flag {$2 = 2;flag = 0}
    1
' OFS=':' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible `sed` solution:

```
    sed  '/17,9:10\/80/,/11:1/ {
          s/8013765024/+118013765024/
          s/11:1/11:2/ }' file.txt
```

This starts the substitution after it finds `17,9:10/80` and first appends `+11` to `8013765024` making it `+118013765024` and it also replaces `11:1` with `11:2` for only the first occurrence of `11:1` (the range is inclusive)

Running `diff` on the output of the `sed` and the initial file shows:

```
    19c19
    < 17,9:10/+118013765024
    ---
    > 17,9:10/8013765024
    21c21
    < ,11:2
    ---
    > ,11:1
```

meaning that the only changes to the file are the addition of [`+11`] and the substitution of [`11:1`] to [`11:2`]. Let me know if this correct.